# Change the theme at runtime in mvc4 using less file

Tags: asp.net-mvc-4

I am new to mvc4. I want to change the theme on runtime in web application. I have site.less file in which I am importing variable.less file(which has all theme settings), on the button click I just want to change @import file. Thanks in advance.